# RecyclerView padding doesn't work under nestedscrollview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need to make a recyclerview which is inside a cardview connected to the appbarlayout inside a Coordinator.

I have the following heirachy setup

```
Coordinator 
  AppBar
  NestedScrollView
    CardView
      Recycler
```

I am unable to attach a padding to the card view. a top margin doesn't work.

**Code**

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nested_scroller"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardElevation="@dimen/elevation_small">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/establishments_rv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

The margintop parameter in the cardview doesn't give any effect.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **android:paddingTop="10dp"** to **NestedScrollView**